# Is $O(2)$ unimodular? (i.e. it left Haar measure is also right invariant.)

Tags: lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices, haar-measure

Is $O(2)$ unimodular? (i.e. it left Haar measure is also right invariant.)

---

We know its connected component $SO(2)$ is unimodular because it’s Abelian. And there is a result says for a connected Lie group, it is unimodular if it is compact or reductive. But this provided with the assumption that $G$ is connected.

---

I guess $O(2)$ is unimodular indeed. But how to give a proof
?

Comment: Exercise: a Lie group $G$ with finitely many components is unimodular iff its unit component $G^\circ$ is unimodular. Hint: $G$ is unimodular iff the action of $G$ by conjugation on $G^\circ$ is measure-preserving.

Comment: @YCor Thanks.  You are right. I have made the exercise. If there is no one answer the question, I will post my solution here later.